# Grouping radio buttons in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, radio-button

I want to present radio buttons in logical products groups:

```
Broadband products:
  (*) 2 Mbit
  ( ) 4 Mbit

Voice products:
  ( ) Standard
  ( ) Total

Bundles:
  ( ) 4 Mbit + Standard
  ( ) 4 Mbit + Total
```

All radio buttons have the same `name` attribute - you get the idea. It seems that Zend Framework 1.8 does not support grouping radio buttons this way. Is there any solution to this?

**Update**. Just to clarify, resulting code should look somewhat this way:

```
Broadband products: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="1"/> 2 Mbit <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="2"/> 4 Mbit <br/>

Voice products: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="3"/> Standard <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="4"/> Total <br/>

Bundels: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="5"/> 4 Mbit + Standard <br/>
<input type="radio" name="product" value="6"/> 4 Mbit + Total <br/>
```

Nevermind the exact formatting code. Only form elements matter.

Comment: This sounds like it might be the same problem. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3541

The reported proposes a fix in his post.

Comment: Are you using Zend_Form?

Comment: Yes, I do use Zend_Form.

Answer (score 12):

You're correct that ZF 1.8 doesn't support grouping of options in this way.  You could easily look at the code inside `Zend_View_Helper_FormRadio` and create your own view helper that supports a multi-dimensional array (ie the select groupings).  I had to do this already for a project, check out the example at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/f1dd448e3)

PHP:

```
$form->addElement('radio', 'test', array(
    'helper'=>'formMultiRadio',
    'label'=>'Test Thing',
    'multiOptions'=>array(
        'Test'=>array('1'=>'1', '2'=>'2'),
        'Test 2'=>array('3'=>'3', '4'=>'4'),
        'Test 3'=>array('5'=>'5', '6'=>'6'),
      ),
  ));
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<dt id="test-label"><label for="test" class="optional">Test Thing</label></dt>

<dd id="test-element">
Test<br />
<label for="test-1"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-1" value="1" />1</label><br />
<label for="test-2"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-2" value="2" />2</label><br />
Test 2<br />
<label for="test-3"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-3" value="3" />3</label><br />
<label for="test-4"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-4" value="4" />4</label><br />
 Test 3<br />
 <label for="test-5"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-5" value="5" />5</label><br />
 <label for="test-6"><input type="radio" name="test" id="test-6" value="6" />6</label>
 </dd>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I needed to wrap a div around each group of radio buttons, and was able to accomplish it in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Zend_Form_Element_Radio

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.radio

There is the multi checkbox class too, but i guess it's only for checkboxes
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiCheckbox

Comment: That's what he's using and is having the problem with.